# how to run more than one command one terminal?

Tags: linux

i have to run "for" loop on linux terminal itself how i can do.
ex.for i in `cat ~/log`;do grep -l "UnoRuby" $i >> ~/logName; done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you typed it should be fine except: `for i in $(cat ~/log); do grep -l "UnoRuby" $i >> ~/logName; done`

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer < instead of cat, and a more friendly format for the quesiton:

```
for i in $(< ~/log)
do
  grep -l "UnoRuby" $i >> ~/logName
done
```